# hamcrest-core: jar:1.4-atlassian-1 could not be resolved on MVN clean install on Spring Boot project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, microservices, hamcrest

Here is my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.mailer</groupId>
    <artifactId>portfolio</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>portfolio</name>
    <description>portfolio services</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mailjet</groupId>
            <artifactId>mailjet-client</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Build logs:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------< com.mailer:portfolio >------------------------
[INFO] Building portfolio 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
.
.
.
[WARNING] The POM for org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.4-atlassian-1 is missing, no dependency information available
.
.
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project portfolio: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failure to find org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.4-atlassian-1 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException
**
```

Any idea why am getting this error related to hamcrest jar? I added the same version of the jar in `.m2/repo/...` but I still get the same error. Any idea which dependency in this POM is using it internally? Do I have to change any version?

Command used to build

```
mvn clean install
```

If I run this project as Spring Boot app then the service is up but what I need is a jar out of this to host in a cloud.

Comment: Which artifact contains a dependency to `org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.4-atlassian-1 ` ? The problem  is simply that artifact is not in central repository (I suppose).. Spring boot does not have such a dependency ...

Comment: @khmarbaise The artifact is definitely not in maven central repo. But somehow some of the dependencies have hamcrest in the dependency tree is what I suspect. But I am not able to figure it out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the issue with my local repository. I had to point to a new repo location under .m2 in settings.xml.